# Find All Instances of a String NOT Within <a> Tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a JavaScript that goes through an html document and finds all instances of a keyword that are NOT links -- not within an `<a>` tag.  For example, let's take the following HTML and I'm looking for the keyword "laptops."

```
<p>I love laptops so much and these are <a href="mylink">some of my <i>favorite laptops</i></a>. Don't you love laptops also?</p>
```

So I need a way to return instances 1 and 3 here, but not number 2, because it is within a link. I'm not sure if the right way to do this is with a Regex (I can't figure out the right one for this) or iterating through the DOM or something. I can use either JQuery or straight JS.

Comment: have you tried anything so far? If so please show it, perhaps we can fix it for you

Comment: What exactly do you want? An array such as `['laptop', 'laptop']` wouldn't be too useful I imagine.

Comment: `instances 1 and 3 here,`  What are you calling instances, because as the DOM goes, you have a `p` element, that contains `a` element, that contains an `i` element.  IOW: your `p` element contains all 3 laptops, so what should we return?.

Comment: Since you're testing against the DOM hierarchy, I would avoid string parsing because that will be extremely difficult and brittle.  A true HTML parser may be appropriate.  Possibly a DOM parser?

Comment: the "problem" is trivial. but not seeing any kind of effort on your side really prevents people to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want a list of elements containing 'laptop', this can get you started:

```js
let elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('*')]
    .filter(e =>
        !e.closest('A') &&
        [...e.childNodes].some(c =>
            c.nodeType === 3 && c.textContent.match(/\blaptops?\b/i)));

elements.forEach(e => e.style.border = '1px solid black');
```

```css
* {padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<div>child text is not considered so this div will not be returned.
  <div>laptop, this div will be returned.</div>
  <div>this div will not.</div>
  <a>laptop in anchor tags are ignored. <span> nested laptop inside anchor tags are also not returned.</span></a>
</div>
<div>plural and capital LapTops will also work, this div will be returned.
  <div>this laptop div will also be returned.</div>
  <div>but parent text is not considered so this div won't be returned.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @canon, no it wont. In fact my snippet includes such an example, take a look at the 1st div "child text is not considered so this div will not be returned"

Comment: I see what you mean. The question's unclear on what expected behavior for your described scenario is, and I prefer assuming the simplest solution is desired. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: You're right again. :) I'll resort to the 'it's trivial to traverse `.parentElement` and check for this case, and the OP will benefit from doing it themselves' argument.

Comment: Updated, didn't even know that method existed, thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It works great, but there's one caveat. If there's more than one instance of the keyword within the element, it doesn't indicate the offset for each or that there is more than one.  And if there are multiple instances within the element and one is linked and one is not, I don't know how to determine which one is which.

Comment: Consider looking into `string.prototype.indexOf` to find offsets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf.